# Program accepts negative number even though I have code to prevent that

Tags: c

I have code that asks the user for a number between 1 - 23.
Then I have this piece of code:

```
if (height > 23) {
    if (height < 0) {
        goto ask;
    }
}
```

For some reason, if I type a number above 23, it asks the user for input again, if I type below 0, it accepts that number. Help?

Also, "height" is stored as an int, if that helps.

Comment: You only check for the number being negative if it is greater than 23.  Numbers larger than 23 are not negative.  You want `if (height > 23 || height < 0) goto ask;`.  Or, if you should not accept 0 (as it is not between 1 and 23), `if (height < 1 || height > 23) goto ask;`.  It would be better still if you manage to avoid using a `goto`; it is probably not necessary if you structure your code correctly (which may involve using functions, which may be material you've not yet covered).

Comment: The code above (op post) really doesn't make sense because if `height` is greater than 23 then it can't also be less than zero.

Comment: Oh, didn't really think this through. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must separate your validations like that:

```
if (height > 23) {
    goto ask;
}
if (height < 0) {
    goto ask;
}
```

You can also make one condition like that:

```
if (height > 23 || height <= 0) {
    goto ask;
}
```

Comment: Explain the change from `height < 0` to `height <= 0`; there are reasons for making that change, but they should be explained.

Comment: You want the number to be between 1 and 23, so zero is not included.. You can also use: `height < 1` 
It's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (height > 23) {
 goto ask;
}
else (height < 0) {
 printf("The number must be higher than 0");
}
```

Comment: In this case, the probable action is the same (`goto ask;`) in both cases.